# vlookup most recent entry/last row where it finds value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to vlookup data from a sheet with two tabs. I know the vlookup will fetch the results from the first search. But desired output, it should look up the value and get the last result.

current vlookup results:
[image: Current vlookup results]

[image: Expected output]

Here is the trix for reference of sample data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WkokpBX59qz33oSbKIKNQ7kNkv4QbNlKUKeBYlK4vy8/edit#gid=0

Any inputs on this is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [XLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) with `search_mode` set to `-1`

```
=ArrayFormula(xlookup(A12:A14,Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!B2:B,,,-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort()` and `row()` to order the data into reverse order, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A2:A10, 
      sort(Sheet2!A1:B, row(Sheet2!A1:B), false), 
      columns(Sheet2!A1:B), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```